# Unit weighted average

Tags: statistics, average, means

Suppose that I have the following sample

| $$\text{Farmer}_{\text{ID}}$$ | $$\text{Farmer}_{\text{Size}}$$ | $$\text{Range}$$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $27$ | $a) \leq 100$ |
| $2$ | $82$ | $a) \leq 100$ |
| $3$ | $91$ | $a) \leq 100$ |
| $4$ | $18$ | $a) \leq 100$ |
| $5$ | $320$ | $b) > 100$ |
| $6$ | $205$ | $b) > 100$ |
| $7$ | $92$ | $a) \leq 100$ |
| $8$ | $48$ | $a) \leq 100$ |
| $9$ | $180$ | $b) > 100$ |
| $10$ | $16$ | $a) \leq 100$ |

([original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcL1Z.png))

and I have some additional information about the two groups, where $87\%$ of the farmers are in the group $a) \leq 100$ and $13\%$ are in group $b) > 100$. How I could calculate a weighted average farm size?

Base in this sample the simple mean of each group is

Group $a \leq 100$: $$\frac{27 + 82 + 91 + 18 + 92 + 48 + 16}{7}\approx 53.4$$

Group $b > 100$: $$\frac{320 + 205 + 180}{3}\approx 235$$

Now if I use the additional information as weights
$$\mu = 0.87 \times 53.4 + 0.13 \times 235 \approx 77$$

this makes any sense?

Comment: Hello and wellcome to Math.SE. You can write tables here with the table function ([see here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4240/how-do-i-insert-a-table-when-asking-a-question)) or via HTML. Please don't just send a picture of a spreadsheet. These images can be difficult to read on certain devices. Hint: In $\LaTeX$ you can write $\geq$ with `\geq` and $\leq$ with `\leq`.